# Delete locked file in Form Templates

Tags: sharepoint-online, check-out, check-in

I am unable to delete a locked file because it says it is checked out by a user. We verified the only user that has access does NOT have this open or checked out. This is in the 'Form Templates' Library that cannot be deleted from the browser.

I also looked into the Library Setting'Manage files which have no checked in version', but nothing shows up there. Any ideas on how to delete this file and/or library? Powershell or another workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the file then delete it:

```
#Variables for Processing
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael"
$LibraryName="doc"
$ItemId="1"

$UserName="michael"
$Password ="xxx"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

#Get the list by title
$List=$Ctx.web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)

#Get the item to delete by ID
$Item=$List.GetItemById($ItemId)
#Get the file to delete
$File=$Item.File

#Check in and delete the file
$File.CheckIn("1",1)
$File.deleteobject()
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for file checked out status and release lock if any

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://prinhyltphp0317/
$listName = "text"
$list = $spWeb.Lists |? {$_.Title -eq $listName}
foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
{
  $itemFile = $item.File
  if( $itemFile.CheckOutStatus -ne "None" )
  { 
           $itemFile.ReleaseLock($itemFile.LockId)
  }
}
```